# 7998: ANSI targets are deprecated

Tags: nsis

How can I resolve *"7998: ANSI targets are deprecated"*?

When I add **Unicode True**

I get error,

> Error: Can't change target charset after data already got compressed or header already changed! 
> Error in script -- on line 58 
> -- aborting creation process

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates your problem

Comment: Add "Unicode True" where? What is the context?

Comment: If you think about it, once you starting writing, to change from pencil to pen and back is destructive. Saying "change to pencil" should be done before writing begins at all. Same thing that message is saying.

Answer (score 16):

`Unicode True` needs to be set very early in your .NSI file, before any `!include` statements and before any `File` commands.

Comment: It can be after `!include` statements. [NSIS Documentation](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#aunicodetarget): _It can only be used outside of sections and functions and before any data is compressed._

Comment: @skst It depends on the header, it is better to just put it first in the script.